# Java REST api not working when deployed to Heroku

Tags: java, rest, heroku

I have been trying to deploy to Heroku a simple `java REST api`.

Now when i run it on Tomcat, I am able to do all the `POST/GET` requests and I am getting the correct responses.

[image: Correct response while deployed locally]

When I finally deployed to Heroku, the starting page is working:
[image: index.jsp working when deployed to Heroku]

but when I send a request I get this reponse:
[image: Error response while deployed on heroku]
The response is the same when i do a `GET` request at `mixas-messenger.herokuapp.com/messenger/webapi/myresource`

The heroku logs when asking for the resource:
[image: Heroku logs when making GET Request to 'myresource']

The web.xml file which handles the API url pattern.
[image: web.xml]

The resource class:
[image: resource class]

Finnaly the contents of the `Procfile` is only this line:
`web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war`

*Note that the project is the maven archetype `jersey.quickstart.webapp` and has not been modified*

Comment: I am new to this, so if there is a key information that is needed and i did not provide, please ask me and i will be happy to.

Comment: Looks like the URL you call is different on Heroku (different path). You should also post some code, for example the endpoint responsible to serve the request

Comment: I only specify the relative path of the resource. Which is the /webapi/*. This will be added to the domain the API is deployed. Or so i think. In both images the path is the same. One time it is deployed to localhost:8080/messenger and the other one at mixas-messenger.herokuapp.com.